# What happens when one consumer thread in ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory fails

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka 2.1 and  have a ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory with concurrency 3,so there are 3 consumers reading from a topic .What happens when one of thread encounters an exception that is not caught .Would all the consumers be shut down and application stopped in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What leads you to ask this question? Have you seen a problem?

The container catches all exceptions and invokes the error handler; what happens next depends on what the error handler does. By default the error is just logged.

If the error occurs in the listener, the error handler gets the record that caused the failure; if the exception occurs outside of the listener invocation, there is obviously no "current" record in that case, but the error handler is still called.

If you configure the container with the `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler`, the entire container (all threads) is stopped.

Comment: Thanks Gary . That makes sense . I had different cases where entire processing should stop if there is an error and other cases where if errors add up to a  certain number then whole process should stop. Used ContainerStoppingErrorHandler for the first case and it works.Ofcourse these are for different consumers

Comment: >By default the error is just logged<.
What happens after this? We get UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID (v0.9 kafka) and the consumers continue to die over the time because of the problem. Is there a way to recover?